# How can I export the javascript whitelist from Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, security, browser, javascript, whitelist

For security reasons I have Javascript disable in Chrome and I use a whitelist of my "trusted" sites. So If I'm surfing the web and I visit a site that is trusted to me then I add it to that list. Maybe is not the best approach in the world, but is  better than allow all.

**Where does Google keep the Javascript whitelist so I can export it later? Do you have a better policy to manage the Javascript of the websites ?**

By the way, I am using Windows 7 x64 :D

- **UPDATE!:**

  The answer given below was really nice but, in my case, I don't have the "Data Sync" folder (maybe because I don't use the Google syncing feature), so I find the javascript whitelist a bit mixed-up within a bunch of JSON data in the *preferences* file. **Do you know at what moment the "Data sync" folder is created?**

Answer (score 2):

The list is stored as a JSON blog inside of a SQLite database.  The database file can be found at:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Sync Data\SyncData.sqlite3
```

Inside that database, the row in the `metas` database where the `non_unique_name` is `profile.content_settings.exceptions.javascript` the `specifics` column contains the JSON payload.

Comment: Firsty, thanks for your reply. I have a problem with that, I don't see the "Sync Data" folder (I have all Windows files visible), maybe is because I never use the "sync" feature from Google.  But I was doing some researching work and I found out that list in JASON format (but in a very meshy way) in the "preferences" file in:     %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\      I am trying t get it from there... :S

Comment: Ps: I was trying to use  mini-Markdown formatting, as code with backticks, in the comment before and It doesn't work (I am new posting here ~_~), so I left it in that way ¬¬.

Comment: I have this file but most of the contents at least by name are encrypted =/.  Always annoyed I have plenty of sync settings turned on and working but this one never seems to..